# Please don't remove sugguested answers while I'm trying to click on them

Tags: feature-request, bug

When you type a new question, it gives you suggestions. There might be several that I want to look at. So I right click on a few to open them in new tabs.

Except, as soon as I right click the first one, the whole list disappears, and then repopulates with different (often less relevant questions)!

The suggestions should not change when you click on one of them. They should only change if you re-title the question.

Comment: when you notice the question aren't you also typing? i notice that they don't change when i click on them but rather when i stop typing and they repopulate

Comment: I don't know. Maybe the text box is focused at the time and becomes unfocused by clicking? I'll have to check next time.

Comment: Yeah, sounds more like a timing issue than an on-click issue.